# Show Name Instead Of Email in email to Sms Gateway python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtplib, sms-gateway

Thats My First question sorry for the mistakes and my english :P

I am currently using a email to sms gateway which is provided by the carriers.
Ex- 1234567890@tmomail.net

But When i send sms using SMTPLIB (Python).
on the receiver side it shows my mail instead of my name.

Current Code I am using -

```py
import smtplib 
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

email = "mymail@gmail.com"
pas = "Your Pass"

sms_gateway = 'number@tmomail.net'

smtp = "smtp.gmail.com" 
port = 587

server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp,port)
server.starttls()
server.login(email,pas)

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = "John Doe <mymail@gmail.com>"
msg['To'] = sms_gateway

msg['Subject'] = "Something...\n"
body = "Something More...\n"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
sms = msg.as_string()

server.sendmail(email,sms_gateway,sms)

server.quit()
```

But when the receiver gets the sms he gets **mymail@gmail.com** as sender not **John Doe**.
I want to hide my mail and allow the receiver to see my name or a provided number.